# CSS image hover doesn't work on Interner Explorer and Firefox

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, firefox, hover

I would like to solve this problem only using CSS and HTML for the moment, as I don't know JavaScript or jQuery yet.

So I have this hyperlink-image that changes (it glows) when I hover on it in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer and Firefox. (Internet Explorer version:11, Firefox version: 26.0)

I read that Internet Explorer recognizes only "anchors", but I don't have any clue how to put the hover in the <a> tab, as the CSS page is separated from the HTML one. I also tried to do write a#x{...}, but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
   <img id="x" style="position:absolute; top:300px; left:950px;" 
    src="images/x.png"/>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#x{
    width:188px;
    height:253px;
}

#x:hover{
    content: url(images/xhover.png);
    width:188px;
    height:253px;
}
```

I tried to change `content` to `background-image`, but the result is that the hover image is in the original size and its height and width won't be modified, and it stays on the background, so the first image won't overlap it... 
I tried to check other posts, but I couldn't find the right solution for me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
content:url(images/xhover.png);
```

to

```
background:url(images/xhover.png);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/4KsBS/)

Comment: I see that this works on IE as well, but now the hover image changes size and it stays on the background, therefore the result is quite ugly... I can't fix it with width and height in the CSS file!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="link">
    <img class="imgHover" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="image">
    <img class="imgHover" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1" alt="image">
</a>


<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .imgHover:first-child{
        display: none
    }

    .link:hover .imgHover:first-child{
        display: block;
    }

    .link:hover .imgHover:last-child{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

The correct way is to use the background, but if you need to use the tag <img> this can be a good solution.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks!