# Creating a hover over image box

Tags: css, image, web, hover

How would I go about creating a CSS box, which when the cursor is hovering over, it turns into another image? I have this so far, can't seem to figure it out. I've got it to be a click to change one, but not a hover over one.

```
<img src="link.jpg"
width="150"
height="150" 
border="1 px"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing image on hover with css/html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html)

Comment: Like the comment above - You could use a plain `<div>` with a `background-image` set, and swap it out on `:hover` (http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/34n8npan/) or if you're stuck using plain images you could get creative. http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/5zsv1pde/

Comment: @Evan the HTML code on the site simply gives me an image, with another image below it

Comment: Cool, are they wrapped in a container or anything? Basically the second fiddle I linked has the second image to be revealed hidden under the first image, when the first image is hovered, it's hidden and reveals the second image. ( you could also sort this out with some `z-index` if needed. Just make sure the wrapper / parent container is relatively positioned like the fiddle ) @ http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/5zsv1pde/

Comment: Ah whoops - just need to set those `<img>` to `display: block / inline-block;` or set a width / height on the div that's containing them and it should sort it out. http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/wxzrmbap/

Comment: @Evan tried that, the image no longer lines up, image one is now on the top-left of image two, and the same issues remains

Comment: Are the two images contained within a `<div>`? Anyway to checkout what you're working on?

Comment: @Evan yes, they are. It either breaks the webpage, or doesn't work xD Using the Weebly editor, custom HTML tool. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Huh, hmm, well you could use 1 `<img>` inside the `<div>` and set a `background-image` to the `<div>` - then, when you hover over the `<img>` / `<div>`, have it `display: none;` to reveal the background of the containing `<div>` ?

Comment: @Evan Hm, not really catching that. I think I'll just move on, cheers for the help though!

Comment: Anytime - but for future reference, Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/d24gujw5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use css `background-image` on a div instead of `img`

```
.your-class {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: (/fakepath/image.jpg);
}
.your-class:hover {
  background-image: (/fakepath/another-image.jpg);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to implement it into a website?

Comment: ..You can do it :) What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like the other anwers - You could use a plain `<div>` with a `background-image` set, and swap it out on :hover (jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/34n8npan) or if you're stuck using plain `<img>`s you could get creative -

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250&text=Image One" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250&text=Image Two" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
div img {
    display: block;
}
div img:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div:hover img:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/2gvzq9eo/

Comment: This works great, however, when the mouse is two-three cm below the picture, it'll still change.