# How to hover picture

Tags: javascript

I like the way it does, *for example* please see profile picture when you hover 'CR' that will show picture on the top, how does it works?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chack the answer of Alois Mahdal from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html)

```
<style>
    #tuxie {
        width: 25px; height: 25px;
        background: url('images/tuxie.png') no-repeat left top;
    }
    #tuxie:hover { background-position: -25px 0px }
</style>

<div id="tuxie" />
```

[image: double image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b72n8L1y/)

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it!  Since I am new here, why I am getting negative points if you don't mind?

Comment: It's because the way you asked the question. SO rule is 'show what you've tried so far' you just can't ask 'how it works' by giving a link. You have to search, then try something, then if you get stuck or can't achieve what you want then you can ask a question with all details. In short you have to try first and show in your question what you've tried. @Carter

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense.  I understand now.  From now on, I will show what I have done so far. @AtanuCSE

Answer (score 1):

This is done with the help of CSS3 attribute which is "transition: all 0.7s ease-out 0s;"
This will show this smooth effect and remaining is normal "hover" property of css.

Read about "transition" property of css for more details.
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/