# Navbar images not hiding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want all the other navbar images to be hidden when the user is on `F+H.html`, and for only `#navbar-image-FH` to show. If a user hovers over the respective navbar item however, then I want the image toggled and the `unhovered` version to be hidden.

I've tried doing this below by using the `.hide` mechanism in javascript, but it doesn't seem to be hiding them properly. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar-item-set">

    <div class="navbar-item" id="navbar-item-ID2Games">

        <a href="index.html" >

            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-unhovered">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-id2games">
            </div>

            <br>
            <div class="navbar-text">
                ID2 Games
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-item" id="navbar-item-FH">

        <a href="F+H.html">

            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-FH-unhovered">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-FH">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="navbar-text">
                Fizz + Hummer
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-item" id="navbar-item-HDS">

        <a href="HDS.html">

            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-HDS-unhovered">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-HDS">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="navbar-text">
                Human Delivery Service
            </div>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-item" id="navbar-item-contact">

        <a href="contact.html" >

            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-contact-unhovered">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-contact">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="navbar-text">
                Contact
            </div>

        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
if (window.location.href.match(/F+H\.html/)){
                $('#navbar-image-FH').show();

                $('#navbar-image-unhovered').hide();
                $('#navbar-image-id2games').hide();
                $('#navbar-image-HDS').hide();
                $('#navbar-image-HDS-unhovered').hide();
                $('#navbar-image-contact').hide();
                $('#navbar-image-contact-unhovered').hide();

                //
                $('#navbar-item-id2games').hover(function() {
                  $('#navbar-image-id2games').toggle();
                  $('#navbar-image-FH-unhovered').hide();
                }, function(){
                         $('#navbar-image-unhovered').toggle();
                         $('#navbar-image-id2games').hide();
                    });

                $('#navbar-item-HDS').hover(function() {
                      $('#navbar-image-HDS').toggle();
                      $('#navbar-image-HDS-unhovered').hide();
                    }, function(){
                             $('#navbar-image-HDS-unhovered').toggle();
                             $('#navbar-image-HDS').hide();
                        });

                $('#navbar-item-contact').hover(function() {
                      $('#navbar-image-contact').toggle();
                      $('#navbar-image-contact-unhovered').hide();
                    }, function(){
                             $('#navbar-image-contact-unhovered').toggle();
                             $('#navbar-image-contact').hide();
                        });
            }
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/bf83mtyL/

Comment: you should probably be doing this with CSS and not JavaScript.  Let me see if I can work up a sample

Comment: what's the difference between (lets say) 'navbar-image-HDS` and `navbar-image-HDS-unhovered' -- they both seem to be empty divs

Comment: @GlennFerrie Theyre basically a color (HDS) and black and white (unhovered) version of an image. In the css I set the background of the divs as the images so thats why the divs look empty.

Comment: Check this out -- pretty straightforward.  I think its a bit easier than what you're trying to do.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html

Comment: @GlennFerrie That's for hover, I'm trying to do the equivalent but for when a link is active, not when a user hovers over something. I tried using the `active` descriptor in CSS but it doesn't work. This js method worked for `index.html` but it isn't working for the others for some reason.