# Is it possible to change img src by hover on another element by CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in CSS to change img src when div element is hovered?

```
<a class="template-image" href="/template-1978944/editor">
 <div class="green"></div>
 <div class="red"></div>
 <div class="orange"></div>
 <img src="/1978944/cover_small.jpg">
</a>
```

I tried

```
a.template-image[href^="/template-1978944"] div.green:hover ~ img {
 content: url(/1978943/cover_small.jpg);"
}

a.template-image[href^="/template-1978944"] div.red:hover ~ img {
 content: url(/1978942/cover_small.jpg);"
}
```

Comment: change 'content' to 'background' and use a transparent image for the image itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing image on hover with CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. Change 'content' to 'background' and use a transparent image for the image `src`

```css
a.template-image[href^="/template-1978944"] div.green:hover ~ img {
 content: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/);"
}

a.template-image[href^="/template-1978944"] div.orange:hover ~ img {
 content: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/);"
}

a.template-image[href^="/template-1978944"] div.red:hover ~ img {
 content: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/);"
}
```

```html
<a class="template-image" href="/template-1978944/editor">
 <div class="green">GREEN</div>
 <div class="red">RED</div>
 <div class="orange">ORANGE</div>
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
</a>
```

UPDATE: if you need the original image, use it image as the default background.

Comment: @PavelBorodaIgnatenko but in this case you are modifying the initial src ... i thought you are not able to change it ? and you need to rely on CSS for that ? ... because if you are able to change src, then why not simply use a div instead of img ?

Comment: @Temani Afif, many thanks to you too.

I will combine bothe code. Yours and this.

Comment: @PavelBorodaIgnatenko there is no issue :) this is also good solution .. but i thought you are not able to touch the HTML and change the image src ;) because if you can you can have more simple solution

Answer (score 4):

You can try some workaround by using `url` of `background-image`:

```css
.orange {
  height:50px;
  background:orange;
}
.img {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
.orange:hover + .img {
  background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/300/)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="orange">Hover me!</div>
<div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/)"></div>
```

You can also create the illusion of changing the `src`by using pseudo-element with no need of markup change *(you simply need to adjust the CSS used to correctly position the new image depending on your code)*

```css
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.orange:hover~img,
.red:hover~img,
.green:hover~img {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.orange:hover::after {
  content: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.red:hover::after {
  content: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/220/);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.green:hover::after {
  content: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/300/);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <br>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the html code :(
This is a part of SaaS and I can change css only.

Comment: Here is should be 3 different divs and each should change img src to different one.

Comment: @PavelBorodaIgnatenko ok updating again :)

Comment: @PavelBorodaIgnatenko check again ;)

Comment: Result should be exactly as @Obsidian Age propose.

Comment: @PavelBorodaIgnatenko check now

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change an image `src` attribute on hover an an element using only CSS.

**However**, it **is** possible to change the **[`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)** property of an element on hover of another element in CSS. If you're willing to use a `<div>` element with a background instead of an `<img>` element, this will give you the same effect.

This can be done with the **[general sibling combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)**, as is seen in the following:

```css
.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100');
}

.green:hover ~ .image {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100/00ff00');
}

.red:hover ~ .image {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000');
}

.orange:hover ~ .image {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100/ffa500');
}
```

```html
<a class="template-image" href="/template-1978944/editor">
  <div class="green">Green</div>
  <div class="red">Red</div>
  <div class="orange">Orange</div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</a>
```

---

If you cannot update the HTML, you'll be forced to rely on a **JavaScript** solution. This can be done by first selecting the image with **[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**, and then adding a function that updates the `.src` of the image during the **[`.onmouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)** of the other elements.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
let image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

document.getElementsByClassName('green')[0].onmouseover = function() {
  image.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100/00ff00';
};

document.getElementsByClassName('red')[0].onmouseover = function() {
  image.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000';
};

document.getElementsByClassName('orange')[0].onmouseover = function() {
  image.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100/ffa500';
};
```

```html
<a class="template-image" href="/template-1978944/editor">
  <div class="green">Green</div>
  <div class="red">Red</div>
  <div class="orange">Orange</div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100">
</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the html code :(
This is a part of SaaS and I can change css only.

Comment: In that case you'll unfortunately be forced to rely on JavaScript to change the attribute on hover. I'll update my answer to hover that as well.

Comment: I've added a JavaScript solution :)