# Hovering Image with another image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replace the image `#about` with another image on hover and no matter what I do I can't get it to work.

Help appreciated thanks!

```
#about {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 117px; 
    padding-top: 100px; 
}

#about:hover {
    background-image: url("about_button2.png"); 
}
```

Comment: is `#about` an `img` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing image on hover with CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html)

Comment: yes. I looked at the "Changing image on hover with CSS/HTML" question and it didn;t help.

Comment: print your html code

Answer (score 0):

```css
#about {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 117px; 
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-color: gray; 
}

#about:hover {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw9tP.png");
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="about"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```