# Can't replace image on hover

Tags: html, css

This never happened to me before, and i can't figure our why the hover happens, but the back image won't change :

```
<div class="settings" id="settings" style="background-image:url(assets/settings.svg);"></div>

.settings{
  width: 2.0vw;
  height: 2.0vw;
  margin-top: calc((8vh - 2vw)/2);
  margin-left: 1.5vw;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.settings:hover{
  background-image: url("assets/settingsH.svg");
}
```

To prove that the image is there, if i set `assets/settingsH.svg` **in the html** - it will show the hover image.

If i change size on hover, it will also work (hover is happening) but back image won't change no matter what.

**No** other hidden `settings` class was found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing image on hover with CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html)

Comment: No. Can you tell me how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you put the background image inline with html, so if you want to replace it via css, you must put an !important:

```
.settings:hover{
    background-image: url("assets/settingsH.svg")!important;
}
```

or bettter, put the background in css:

```css
.settings {
  width: 2.0vw;
  height: 2.0vw;
  margin-top: calc((8vh - 2vw) / 2);
  margin-left: 1.5vw;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/400/0000FF");
}

.settings:hover {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/400/FF0000");
}
```

```html
<div class="settings" id="settings"></div>
```