why aren'tmy hover images are not aligning in HTML
I have two images for each button on my site, one that is the base version of the button, and one for when you hover over the button.
the hover image for my 'blog' button is showing up on top of the button above it. (imaged below, i made but button 50% transparent so you could see the issue)
(https://i.sstatic.net/Hn98U1Oy.png)
(i know this code is not very good, I only started learning 4 days ago and am just making this test site for now)
I have tried following some different tutorials online but I have gotten stuck on how to fix this issue.


.buttonlinks {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.buttonlinks img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.aboutmehover {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.aboutmehover:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

.bloghover {
        position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.bloghover:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

.interestshover {
            position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:15;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.interestshover:hover {
       opacity:1; 
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

            <!-- Left Section -->
            <div class="column left" style="background-color: rgba(125, 77, 77, 0)">
                <div class="buttonlinks">
                    <!-- LEFT SIDE BUTTON LINKS -->
                    <a href="otherpages/about-me.html"><img src="buttons/about-me.png" alt="About Me Button"/></a>
                    <a href="otherpages/about-me.html"
                        ><img class="aboutmehover" src="buttons/about-me-hover.png" alt="About Me Button"/></a>
                    <a href="otherpages/blog.html"><img src="buttons/blog.png" alt="About Me Button" /></a>
                    <a href="otherpages/blog.html"><img class="bloghover" src="buttons/blog-hover.png" /></a>
                    <a href="buttons/interests.png"><img src="buttons/interests.png"></a> 
                    <img class="interestshover" src="buttons/interests-hover.png">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column null" style="background-color: rgba(125, 77, 77, 0)">
                <p></p>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>




When posting code, use a [repro] and pay extra attention to the word minimal. I also see no buttons in your code just a few anchors with images that do not run here. Also, note that your anchors are completely inaccessible (you should not use images with text as buttons).

There is no reason for you to have two a hrefs for each state. Keep one a href and try to change the background-image like so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html

I tried changing the background image before I did this and it didn't work. I will try again, thank you

Like I said in my previous comment there is no need for you to keep two a href and switch between them, so here is one example based on your code that uses one a href tag that switches pictures based on if a user hovers it or not.


.buttonlinks {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.buttonlinks img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#about-me{
  display:block;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.co/100x50?text=About-Me');
  height: 50px;
   width: 100px;
}

#about-me:hover{
  background-image: url('https://placehold.co/100x50?text=About-Me-Hover');
}

#blog{
  display:block;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.co/100x50?text=Blog');
  height: 50px;
   width: 100px;
}

#blog:hover{
  background-image: url('https://placehold.co/100x50?text=Blog-Hover');
}

#interests{
  display:block;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.co/100x50?text=Interests-Me');
  height: 50px;
   width: 100px;
}

#interests:hover{
  background-image: url('https://placehold.co/100x50?text=Interests-Hover');
}
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="column left" style="background-color: rgba(125, 77, 77, 0)">
        <div class="buttonlinks">
          <a href="otherpages/about-me.html" id="about-me"></a>
          <a href="otherpages/blog.html" id="blog"></a>
          <a href="buttons/interests.html" id="interests"></a> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column null" style="background-color: rgba(125, 77, 77, 0)">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>




On my page now, following this code, the images are duplicated twice, the hover works now but each button/image is on the page twice and on top of each other

Could you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ and share the code with me, so I can have a better view of the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/metalZS/eyxfa2m4/2/ I was not sure if you wanted all the code or just this portion, let me know if you want just this little portion and I will change it. I put the placeholder images back in, but on my page it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/wtBKyCA

I see, it's because the image you are providing is smaller than the container a href so it repeats itself to fill in the empty space. Look into this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.php

What you can also do is since you are setting the a hrefs as 300px by 50px to adjust the image accordingly
